# Access GPIO pins inside and outside a class

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a script which accesses sets of GPIO pins for LED control and motor control.
One aspect of the Motor control is contained in a class for threading, the other is a separate function which also accesses the same GPIO pins. 
Will I need to pull all motor control into the same class, or can I access them from both places?

```
def MotorControl(direction,fspeed,bspeed):
  print "Controlling them pins"
  if direction == "fwd":
    bck.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    fwd.ChangeDutyCycle(fspeed)
    print "forward at" + str(fspeed) + "%"
    return
 if direction == "bwd":
    bck.ChangeDutyCycle(bspeed)
    fwd.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    print "back at" + str(bspeed) +  "%"
    return

class sliderControl(threading.Thread):
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO_PWM1=14
    GPIO_PWM2=15
    GPIO_SW1=11

    GPIO.setup(GPIO_PWM1,GPIO.OUT)
    fwd = GPIO.PWM(GPIO_PWM1, 250)
    fwd.start(0)
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_PWM2,GPIO.OUT)
    bck = GPIO.PWM(GPIO_PWM2, 250)
    bck.start(0)
    #Setup input for switch monitoring
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_SW1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


    def __init__(self,stop_event):
            super(sliderControl,self).__init__()
            self.stop_event = stop_event
            GPIO.cleanup()
    def run(self):
            while   self.stop_event:
                    print 'forward loop'
                    bck.ChangeDutyCycle(10)
                    fwd.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print 'backwards loop'
                    bck.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
                    fwd.ChangeDutyCycle(20)
                    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help but feel that the following code:

```
GPIO_PWM1=14
GPIO_PWM2=15
GPIO_SW1=11
```

would be better as constants at the top of your entire program, at which point you could just call upon them from anywhere in the program to output to them, and then this entire problem would cease to be.